# SQL combine 2 separate queries and show total

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables. Users, Things, Objects.

Users can add both things and objects. I want to count how many things, objects, and also total of both users have added. I have it started but having trouble bringing the second table in. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf6927/9

**Objects Table:**

id, added_by, object_name

**Things Table:**

id, added_by, thing_name

**Users Table:**

id, username

**Ideally the results would look like this:**

Username - Total Objects Added - Total Things Added - Total of Both

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dccb/6)**

```
SELECT username, coalesce(objects,0) as objects, coalesce(things,0) as things,   
coalesce(objects,0)+coalesce(things,0) as total
FROM users left join
(
   select user_id, count(*) as objects from table1
   group by user_id
)t1 on t1.user_id = users.id
left join 
(
  select user_id, count(*) as things from table2 
  group by user_id
)t2
on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
```

Comment: If the user doesn't have anything in one of the tables rather than show 0 it doesn't show that user at all. Any idea how to fix that? sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dccb/3

Comment: @steaksauce, I've updated the answer - you can check here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dccb/6

Comment: That did it. Thanks again!